# Check that array does not contain falsy values in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to create a unit test with Jest to make sure my array called `values` does not contain falsy values.

This for some reason does not work - the test passes:

```
const badValues = ['', null, undefined, false, {}, []];
expect(values).toEqual(expect.not.arrayContaining(badValues));
```

Below code works as expected (test fails), but surely there must be a proper way instead of looping over my values?

```
for (const value of values) {
  expect(value).toBeTruthy();
}
```

Comment: Neither `{}` nor `[]` are "falsy".

Comment: @Pointy You are half right. `{}` is not falsy, while `[]` is actually falsy. Try `[] == false` in your browser.

Comment: Try `[] ? alert("truthy") : alert("falsy")` in *your* browser.

Comment: [] is an empty array, and a reference to *any* object is always truthy. The `==` operator is not a good way to test that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible iterating over `badValues` and then `includes()` if `values` and `badValues` are both arrays of strings or numbers, not objects.

```js
const badValues = ['', 'null', 'undefined', 'false', '{}', '[]'];

var values = [1,2,3,4,'null',5];


for(let i = 0; i<badValues.length; i++){

   if(values.includes(badValues[i])){
       console.log("bad value present");
       break;
   }

}
```

Otherwise, I think there is no better way than iterating over `values`. It could be possible using `test()` and regex, but `[`,`]`,`{`,`}` are all special characters in regex expressions. So we should escape them.

Comment: Comparing objects and arrays like that does not make any sense becase comparison like `[] === []` or `{} === {}` alyways return false.`.includes` wont work with them.

Comment: @JanCiolek Yes, that is true, I guessed op had strings. In your case there is no way iterating badvalues.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can work:

```
var isValid = arrayOfValuesToBeChecked.reduce(function(prev, elem) {
    // If elem is not truthy and if it is object, check its length 
    elem = elem ? typeof(elem) == 'object' ? elem instanceof Array ? elem.length : Object.keys(elem).length : elem : elem;
    return prev && elem;
}, true);
```